# Redirect a page to an aspx page works in chrome but not in IE

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, redirect, meta

I searched for a way to redirect index.htm page in "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" to my aspx login page.I added this line in the index.htm file:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://hfp.com/login.aspx" />
```

It works in chrome but when I open it with IE shows a blank page.why IE doesn't redirect it and how to make it possible?

Comment: syntax problem maybe? try `content="0;URL='http://hfp.com/login.aspx'"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meta-refresh doesn't work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522353/meta-refresh-doesnt-work)

Comment: Also you can try to use `URL` uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats an security FEATURE in IE if your Browse-configuration is set to th level "High", you cant refresh  to another page in IE, or you have to lower the Security Level