# Form re-submitting in Edge browser

Tags: vb.net, meta-tags

I have a simple form one button and a gridview. When the user clicks the button their name and the time they clicked is logged. I am using a meta tag to refresh the page every 30 seconds. It works fine in IE, Chrome, and Firefox but, on Edge browsers when it refreshes it gives the user a pop up to resubmit every time to resubmit and logs them again every time.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
    <form id="form1" runat="server">    
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Pick Up"/>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PLUSER" HeaderText="User" S 
             SortExpression="name" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PLDATE" HeaderText="Date" 
             SortExpression="timeDate" ItemStyle-Width="250px" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
```

Is there a setting or something special about edge in relation to meta tags?

Comment: What was the point of offering the bounty if you were just going to answer the question yourself?

Comment: Hoping someone else will know why the meta tag didn't work but put what we ended up using. Never could get the meta refresh to work the timer is more of a work around if someone else figures out the meta want to give them the bounty.

Comment: Ok makes sense. I was curious.

Comment: Yea the timer works but that meta refresh was working in all browsers but edge and that is the real question. But I think it is just edge being edge.

Comment: definite edge case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if someone else figures out why the meta tag fails in Edge...

I've found a few reasons why the META tag doesn't work in Edge browsers.

1. Security Settings:

There is a security setting in internet explorer that does not allow meta tag refresh. It is under the Security tab, then choose Custom Level and the Meta Tag Refresh under Miscellaneous. If that is disabled, it would stop the meta refresh from working.

2. It might need you to specify the URL in the Content:

   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;**URL**=http://www.Stackoverflow.com">
3. The META tag is not an empty tag and does not have a closing tag in HTML, only in XHTML.

So HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

XHTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"> </meta>
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522353/).

---

I'm afraid even with all these potential solutions it still wont work in Edge. 
A good workaround is using progressive enhancement like you've done with the Script Manager, another method is using Javascript directly here: https://davidwalsh.name/meta-refresh-javascript

```
<script>
    ESPN_refresh=window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.href=window.location.href},900000);
</script>
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900" />
</noscript>
```

> Use JavaScript as your primary means for automatic page refreshes and a META tag as your fallback.

Comment: The second solution worked adding the URL to the meta tag but going to leave the timer in.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this for all browsers ended up using a asp.net timer instead of the meta tag and it works in edge as well as the other browsers.

HTML

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>           
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server"></asp:Timer>
```

Vb.Net

```
Dim MinuteCount = 0
Dim x = "off"
Dim count As Integer = 0

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (Not IsPostBack Or x = "off") Then
        MinuteCount = 0
        Timer1.Interval = 60 * 500
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        x = "on"
    End If      
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    x = "off"
    Label1.Text = "Checked at: " & DateTime.Now()
    checkData()
End Sub
```